# BASH_REMATCH with / character

Tags: linux, bash

Hi I have a text file like this:

```
# mysite.online (host ok)
192.168.0.10,0
192.168.1.3,0
# mysite.ch (host ok)
192.168.0.11
192.168.1.4
# mysite2.online (host ok)
192.168.0.12
192.168.1.9
# mysite2.ch (host ok)
192.168.0.13
192.168.1.11
# mysite.ch/home.html (url ok)
192.168.0.15
192.168.1.169
```

I need to read the single line and capture the hostname and the IP:
I'm using this code:

```
while read -r line
  do
    if [[ $line =~ ([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+)\ \((host|url)\ ok\) ||
      $line =~ ([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){3})\ \(IP\ ok\) ]]; then
      host="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    elif [[ $host != "" ]]; then
      if [[ $line =~ ^([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){3}) ]]; then
        ip="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        check_site $host $ip
      fi
    fi
  done < <(echo -e "$chunk") &
```

But I have a problem to capture host when there is a / character,
for example the host
`# mysite.ch/home.html (url ok)`
returns only
`home.html`
and not
`mysite.ch/home.html`.

How can fix it?

Comment: `[a-zA-Z0-9./-]+`? Maybe just `[^ ]+` and call it a day? `I'm using this code:` Have you wrote that code? Do you understand that code?

Comment: `[a-zA-Z0-9.-]` doesn't match "/" (or a bunch of other legal URL characters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
 if [[ $line =~ ([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+)\ \((host|url)\ ok\) ||
          $line =~ ([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){3})\ \(IP\ ok\) ]]; then
```

to this:

```
 if [[ $line =~ ([a-zA-Z0-9./-]+)\ \((host|url)\ ok\) ||
          $line =~ ([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){3})\ \(IP\ ok\) ]]; then
```

Comment: Consider to explain **why**  your solution works.